# how to solve the JSON response?

Tags: web-services, json, rest, httpresponse

**Hi,
 I am doing REST web service.
When I request the GET/ POST method, the response is 200 OK.
But I want to get the response with key,value. so i write like this:**

```
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getContainer(@Context HttpHeaders headers){

        mongoDAOImpl impl=new mongoDAOImpl();
        Mongo mongo=impl.getConnection("127.0.0.1","27017");
        DB db=impl.getDataBase(mongo,"public");
        DBCollection coll=impl.getColl(db,"public");
        mongoDTO dto=new mongoDTO();


    try{
        DBCursor dbcur=impl.findAllRecords(coll);
        DBObject o;
        while(dbcur.hasNext()){
            o=dbcur.next();

        }
        if(dbcur==null){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }else{
            String respStr=dto.toJson(false);
         return Response.ok(respStr).header("Specification-version", "1.0").build();
          }
    }
        catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).tag("Container Read Error : " + ex.toString()).build();
     }
    }
```

But I got the result is

`GET /web/jersey/resources/cloud/juniarto

 HTTP/1.1

 User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0

 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18

 Host: localhost:26235

 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK

 X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0

 Server: GlassFish Server

 Open Source Edition 3.0.1

 Specification-version: 1.0

 Content-Type: application/json

 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

 Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2011 00:56:48 GMT

 Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

 Closing connection #0 Error:org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a 
 field name, expecting a values`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Jersey are you using? Does your JSON output contain any arrays?

It looks like you're experiencing [JERSEY-478](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-478). Try updating to Jersey 1.5 or later.